# Reverse engineering a flutter built apk

Tags: decompilation, c++, android, unpacking, apk

I was trying to reverse engineer an apk built with `flutter`. I actually feel like reversing flutter built apps did not get much reverse writeups on the community. one of the tools for the task `reflutter` which I used in this case failed because the `flutter` version built with the `apk` is not supported by the `reflutter`. so the author provided  [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/ptswarm/reflutter) in which one allows to implement his own patches there is manual Flutter code change is supported using specially crafted Docker. but the environment variables passed there, included `HASH_PATCH=[Snapshot_Hash]` `COMMIT=[Engine_commit]`. in this case if I know the `snapshot Hash` from the `apk` how can I get the matching `Engine commit` for example in this case this is `Engine SnapshotHash: adb4292f3ec25074ca70abcd2d5c7251`, so how can I retrieve the matching `Engine Commit`?

Comment: I am facing the same problem (same snapshot hash), Digging in google i found a commit in github with the engine hash that matches our hash, but, after executing the docker command, it fails. I tried to execute it in a docker instance but it fails. Commit: https://github.com/jayluxferro/custom-flutter-engines/pull/72 The docker command i tried is: docker run -e WAIT=300 -e x64=0 -e arm=0 -e HASH_PATCH=adb4292f3ec25074ca70abcd2d5c7251 -e COMMIT=ada363ee93b17cfe31587b5102679885cb40837e --rm -iv$(pwd):/t ptswarm/reflutter I also tried to modify the source code of reflutter to force the program to

Comment: ... "use that engine hash and i was able to generate the apk but i cant intercept traffic so i think it didn't work" would the above comment continue. It was posted as answer, when it clearly isn't one, though.

Comment: @MarioRuano do you still get any solution for this? I mean what was the error failure from the docker?

Comment: @MarioRuano when I try to build the docker image it hangs at 1:23:48 time every time I tried to build it. the logs don't get update such time. are we seeing same?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like https://github.com/Impact-I/reFlutter/blob/main/enginehash.csv is a definite source of these `versions`, `Engine_commit` and `Snapshot_Hash`

So from there

| version | Engine_commit | Snapshot_Hash |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3.7.12 | 1a65d409c7a1438a34d21b60bf30a6fd5db59314 | adb4292f3ec25074ca70abcd2d5c7251 |

PS: https://github.com/ptswarm/reFlutter/ is archived and https://github.com/Impact-I/reFlutter is recently updated.

The snapshot hash is calculated by [this script](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/tools/make_version.py)

The `dart_revision` mentioned [here](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/main/DEPS#L56) is a commit from [dart/sdk](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/commit/f1387834bfd9f9259c969aff217ec19c2d15a3e0)

So to effectively know where does this hash belong to - we need to checkout different commits of https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk, generate the snapshot hash of each and check where was the commit referenced in https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/main/DEPS

I see that this has been implemented in https://github.com/Impact-I/reFlutter/blob/main/scripts/gen_enginehash.py to generate the CSV linked above. It would make sense to read this script and see if it misses something.